# AS3 ScrollPane number of items

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scrollpane

everyone.

Can I get a number of items from a ScrollPane component in Flash? If yes, then how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollPane has one item which is the source parameter.  If you want to know all the children within that source (and it's a DisplayObjectContainer),  you can use the .numChildren property of the SOURCE.

If you want all the sub-children, you could iterate through all the children until you have you're final number:

```
var d:DisplayObjectContainer = scrollPane.source;

function countChildren(container:DisplayObjectContainer):int {
    var count:int = container.numChildren;
    var tmp:DisplayObject;
    var i:int = count;
    while(i--){
        tmp = container.getChildAt(i);
        if(tmp is DisplayObjectContainer){
            count += countChildren(tmp);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

so call countChildren() with the source of the scrollPane.

```
if(scrollPane.source is DisplayObjectContainer){
    countChildren(DisplayObjectContainer(scrollPane.source));
}
```

Comment: Well, .numChildren worked, however, it tells me I only have 3 items, when there are actually 4.

Comment: is one of the four a child of one of the other three?  .numChildren only reports the immediate children of a display object.  Use the countChildren function I made to get the number of all children no matter how far down the line they are.

Comment: and are you using scrollpane.numChildren,  or scrollpane.source.numChildren?

Comment: I'm using scrollpane.numChildren.

Comment: that's your issue then.  use .numChildren on the source of the scrollpane.     DisplayObjectContainer(scrollPane.source).numChildren

Comment: Sorry to pester you with my stupidity, but the number is stored in "count", right?

Comment: If you're referring the countChildren function,  the function returns the number.   so you could do:   var howMany:int = countChildren(myscrollpanesource);

Comment: Well, I got a whole bunch of errors: 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type flash.display:DisplayObject to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.

1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.

1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type Class.

Comment: Are you casting the source?   source is a display object so you needs to cast it to DisplayObjectContainer.  eg.  DisplayObjectContainer(scrollpane.source)

Comment: update you're question with your code and I can help you more

Answer (score 0):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#numChildren

Should have a numChildren if the objects you're talking about are actual direct descendants of the ScrollPane in question.

Comment: ScrollPane.numChildren will report all the child objects of the scroll pane, which could include things like the scroll bars and mask.

Comment: Oh, rats. I just wanted the XML children that were fed into this ScrollPane. Unfortunately, whenever I use myXML.list.length(), it just gives me an undefined error (my XML structure is XML > List > Viewer, and I want the number of "viewer" nodes/children).